# Should I Re-Use Cutout Drywall Sections?

Tags: drywall

I recently cut out channels in the wall to install a new outlet and cable pass throughs for a Samsung Frame TV in my office. I used a cutout tool so have the original pieces intact. In terms of the repair - mostly concerned about the results - is it OK to re-use the existing pieces with new drywall screws and mud over that? I cut stud to stud so have ability to mount back to studs themselves. Or should I cut fresh drywall and do the same? I have all of the materials and tools necessary so only consideration is whether ease of reusing the cutout pieces will result in a good finish. If re-using, should I tape joints? They are tight so was going to feather edges to allow mud to penetrate a bit.
Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: Before you cut, I would have advised you to make your cuts at an angle, in towards the hole.  Then you could have place mud into the edges and pushed you piece back in, a touch more in than the wall.  It would have made the skimming repairs easier with less feathering.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reuse the pieces you cut out.

You feathered the edges, so it sounds as if you know what you are doing.

I prefer to tape and mud, but in a pinch I have just mudded the seam and got no cracks.  It depends on how much movement there may be in the framing underneath.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the stud-to-stud piece you have. You should use a tape, otherwise a slight pressure from someone resting their hand near it could make it separate.  It is a fair amount of work to plaster and paint it so that the join does not show up.

One word of warning though: make sure it's not labelled `bracing` or `braceline`.  If it is then you should replace the whole sheet.  Around here it is blue in colour.